# custom service respond me : 401 Unauthorized: Missing required argument foo

Tags: 7, services

I have this custom service:

```
function zbs_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'productQuestionForm' => array(
      'actions' => array(
        'send' => array(
          'help' => 'save a FOO entity via send form',
          'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'zbs'),
          'callback' => '_zbs_productQuestionForm_create',
          //'access arguments' => array('note resource create'),
          //'access arguments append' => FALSE,
          'args' => array(
              array(
                'name' => 'foo',
                'type' => 'struct',
                'description' => 'The FOO to create',
                'source' => 'data',
                'optional' => false,
              ),
            ),
        ),
      )
    )

  );
}
```

And this little jQuery code in a simple html test file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/rest1/productQuestionForm/send",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','X-CSRF-Token':'MY_WORKING_TOKEN' },
    success: function (res) {
      alert("success");
      console.log(res);
    },
    data : {
      'foo' : 'pippo',
      "type":"page",
      "title":"Page submitted via entity JSON REST",
      "body": {
          "value": "<p>test</p>\n",
          "format": "filtered_html"
      }
    },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
  });
```

But when I load the simple test html page I see this in developer suite for the POST url:

> 401 Unauthorized: Missing required argument foo

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't the type mismatched from the service definition and the POST data?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the mismatch between the data type you define for foo (`'struct'`), and what you pass with JavaScript (a string). If you are going to pass a string, then your hook implementation should be the following one.

```
function zbs_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'productQuestionForm' => array(
      'actions' => array(
        'send' => array(
          'help' => 'save a FOO entity via send form',
          'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'zbs'),
          'callback' => '_zbs_productQuestionForm_create',
          //'access arguments' => array('note resource create'),
          //'access arguments append' => FALSE,
          'args' => array(
              array(
                'name' => 'foo',
                'type' => 'string',
                'description' => 'The FOO to create',
                'source' => 'data',
                'optional' => false,
              ),
            ),
        ),
      )
    )
  );
}
```

`'source' => 'data'` is perfectly fine, as shown in the example at [`hook_services_resources()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!docs!services.services.api.php/function/hook_services_resources/7), but notice what the documentation says.

> In the case of 'data' unless you put things in an array, you will get passed to your functions. `'source' => array('data' => 'nid')` will pass them off as a single variable; `'source' => array('data')` will give you all argument values to each argument.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
'source' => 'data',
```

to

```
'source' => array('data' => 'foo'),
```

Clear the caches, and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, but no. It does not work. Thanks, however.

Comment: did you clear cache and re-save your endpoint after making this change?